# Set LockOutEndDate to null ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to unlock a user account from the admin panel:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> EnableAccount(string id)
        {
            var user = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            if(user != null)
            {
                await UserManager.ResetAccessFailedCountAsync(user.Id);
                await UserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user.Id, null );
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Users");
        }
```

I'm getting this error:
`cannot convert from '<null>' to 'DateTimeOffset'` in

`await UserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user.Id, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it this way:

```
var user = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
user.LockoutEndDateUtc = null;
user.LockoutEnabled = false;
```